# Add `overlay` modifiers from an array | Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an array that contains a bunch of elements with their preferred alignment. I am trying to add elements from this array to a view through the `overlay` modifier. However, I am not able to get it to work. Here is what I've tried till now

```swift
 struct ContentView: View {
    struct ViewText {
        var label: String
        var alignment: Alignment
        var id: String
    }
    
    var viewArray: [ViewText] = [
        ViewText(label: "Hello 1", alignment: .topLeading, id: "1"),
        ViewText(label: "Hello 2", alignment: .topTrailing, id: "2"),
        ViewText(label: "Hello 3", alignment: .bottomLeading, id: "3"),
        ViewText(label: "Hello 4", alignment: .bottomTrailing, id: "4")
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        var backgroundView = Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.red)
        
        ForEach(viewArray, id: \.id) { element in
            backgroundView.overlay(alignment: element.alignment) {
                Text(element.label).foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

The result of the above code 
[image: Result of the above code]

Expected Result 
[image: Expected result]

The above code does not work. It adds multiple background views for each overlay that is present in the array. Any idea on how I can get it to work? Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ZStack`, which can work with `ForEach`, and also overlays views on top of each other.

```
Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .overlay {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(viewArray, id: \.id) { element in
                Text(element.label).foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: element.alignment)
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that I used `maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity` to make the `ZStack` to match the frame of the `Rectangle`.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  To keep the question simple, I shared a simple example, but in my project, these Text labels could be full-fledged views with backgrounds. I tried setting the background color for one of these elements and it painted the entire rectangle.

Comment: @SarthakMishra Did you put the background color after `frame`? You should put it before `frame`.

Comment: @SarthakMishra If you put `background` before `frame` and it still doesn't work, I cannot reproduce that. I'd suggest making a new post and include a [mcve].

Comment: You are right. I used it after setting the frame, let me try before that.